# Am I being over-complicated for a parser?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns

This is more a design question that a technical question, but since there is a tag called `design-patterns` I think it makes sense.

My scenario is as follows: I have a CSV file, that I want to use to populate an object and then use that object for making an API call. So far so good.

The tricky part is that the CSV data could require some conversions before populating the object, and once the object is created and populated I want to edit some of those object properties.

The view and controller operations are going to be provided by angular and I have focused on the template stuff.

How is the object composed? Well, my idea is as follows:

- The result will be a hasmap of objects, where each object has a collection of fields which are also objects. This object represents a row, and each field a column.

  - Each field will have a `value` property, this way angular can do it's two way data binding magic. It will have also a set of methods for querying and interacting with the object, like asking for the object class (`ng-dirty` if it is required and empty), adding another element if it is a collection instead of a single value, and that kind of things.

To build this object I will proceed this way:

- First build a set of rules for parsing each column/field data.
- Each rule has a parser method that parses the data, and a constructor method, which returns the "field" object I mentioned above.
- The constructor calls the parser, which will parse the data and return a valid representation of that data. The constructor will then return an object field with the parser result as value and a set of method for interacting with that object.
- Rules are created using the ruleFactory function. This function receives the "type" of the field, if it is required (mandatory) or not, the constructor to use and an object for additional options such the parser to use and returns a rule.

Some constructors are built on top of other constructors. For example, the basic constructor is used by the `arrayConstructor`, that extends the object the basic constructor returns and then returns it. The `arrayConstructor` is used by the `limitedValuesConstructor` and so on. If you did not noticed, some constructors falls back to a default parser if it is not defined.

My idea wish is that this is extensible, so if in the future if the format of the data changes, I just add another parser, or I update an existing parser. Same stuff for the constructors.

But, I feel that I'm going to complicated for this task, and I want your opinion about it. Another thing that scares me a lot is that I feel that this does not fit under any valid design pattern that I know. It is not prototypical, not classical, not a module pattern (closure) and I'm not familiar with composition, but I feel that this is not valid composition neither.

Below you can find the basic code inside a closure.

```
    (function () {
     function ruleFactory (type,required,constructor,options) {
        constructor = constructor || basicConstructor;
        var column = {
            'type': type,
            'required': required || false,
            'parser': options && options.parser ,
            'constructor': function (data) { return constructor.apply(column,[data,required,options])}
        };
        return column
    }

    function strParser (data){
        if( typeof data === "string" ){
            return data
        } else if( data && data.toString){
            return data.toString();
        }
        return ''
    }

    function arrParser (data){
        if(!data){
            return []
        }
        if( angular.isArray(data) ){
            return data
        }
        return strParser(data).split(' ');
    }

    function basicConstructor (data,required) {
        var parser = this.parser || strParser; //fallback to the most basic parser
        var column = {};
            column.value = parser(data);
            column.getClass = function (){
                if( required && ! this.value ){
                    return 'ng-dirty'
                }
                return ''
            };
            return column
    }

    function arrConstructor (data,required) {
        this.parser = this.parser || arrParser; // default parser for this constructor
        var column = basicConstructor.apply(this,arguments);
        column.addValue = function (value) {
            column.value.push(value);
        }
        column.getClass = function ( ) {
            if ( column.value.length <= 0 && required ) {
              return 'ng-dirty'
            }
            return ''
        }
        return column
    }

})()
```

The "rules" object (or array or whatever you want) is built like this:

```
var rules  = {
            "someColName": ruleFactory('number',true), // true means required. Defaults to false
            "someList" :  ruleFactory('array',false,arrConstructor), //No parser defined, so fallbacks to default parser for arrConstructor
            "otherList" :  ruleFactory('array',false,arrConstructor, {parser:arrParser}) }
```

Any opinion / constructive criticism is very welcome.

Regards

Comment: This is way too long and never narrows down to a specific question or problem

Comment: I have reduced to the basic set of constructors. As I said, is not a specific problem, but a design question.

Comment: Won't get much help when you write a novel

Comment: I'd rather have to much information than to little.

Comment: I would separate the 'parsing' of the csv file (split on new lines, split on commas, reorg) and manipulating that data. Once its in one of the two native javascript data structures (and prior to ES 6 there are only two: POJO and Array) then worry about processing. `var data = csv.split('\n').map(function(x) {return x.split(',');}); var headings = data[0]; var types = data[1]; /*or however your csv is structured*/ var stuff = data.slice(2).map(function(row, i) { return row.map(function(col, j) { var type = types[j]; var heading = headings[j]; /*do stuff*/}));`

Comment: the part where I have `/*do stuff*/` is pretty much the only actual business logic of the process, everything else is just the fundamental operation of breaking up a csv.

Comment: Design questions are [not a good fit for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) . Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i agree with you that you're over-thinking it. it doesn't seem that complex to adjust a processing pipeline without all the formalities you cover, especially if you have a few generic reusable functions to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: @JuanMendes I thought design questions should go to programmers.se? E.g., if you're thinking of your problem at the *keyboard*, then it's SO; if you're thinking of your problem at the *whiteboard*, then it's programmers.se.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator if you have working code that you want reviewed, CodeReview is a good bet (but make sure to read their guidelines). If you have a design question Programmers.SE is a good place. In this case it doesn't look like this code is functional yet so the question is more, "how can I design this class?" which is a better fit on Programmers.SE. But it's not clear if the question is feedback on working code or feedback on mostly working code.

Comment: Thanks to all of those that have pointed to other portals such codereview.stackexchange.com or programmers.se. I did not know those portals, and I will ask there. Should I remove this question then?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator - the design portion of this question is primarily opinion based and not a good fit for Programmers.  For instance "But, I feel that I'm going to complicated for this task, and I want your opinion about it." and "Any opinion / constructive criticism is very welcome."

Comment: @Danielo515 - Please don't re-ask this question on Programmers, it will get closed as primarily opinion based.  As far as code review, you _really_ need to review their help / on-topic page first before asking.  If you do re-ask elsewhere, yes, you should close and delete the question here.

Comment: Thank you @GlenH7, I'm not sure why do you think it is opinion based. It is true that I express my doubts about it, but I want to know if it fits in any design patter or if it is an absolute mess. I have been investigating more design patterns, and I'm still not able to fit this design in any of those. But, apart from my doubts, I don't think it is a 100% bad implementation. Regards